# win32gui / pywinauto don't see which child objects the component consists of

Tags: pywinauto, win32gui

Please tell me how you can find out what elements the component (TDBGridEh) of the user interface of another application consists of. Or explain why no automation API (neither win32 nor uia) provides information on it
[details on the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gEpt.png)

Context: I am creating a python application to automate another application written in Delphi. It was possible to use the win32gui to control elements such as TCheckBox, Static, SysListView32 by sending messages using SendMessage. pywinauto also managed to extract data from the TPairTreeViewCheck component. But it doesn't work out for TDBGridEh in any way. What could be the problem and how can I get access to it?

Comment: If it is Delphi application, I'd recommend to ask developers to apply this UI automation support library: https://github.com/jhc-systems/DelphiUIAutomation If it is not possible, I guess grid can't be easily automated even with pywinauto.

Comment: @VasilyRyabov Thanks for the comment! 
Apparently, I explained it badly, but the automation program is written in PyQt, and the Delphi application needs automation. Therefore, DelphiUIAutomation will not fit apparently. Thanks again!

Comment: Of course, DelphiUIAutomation is not applicable to PyQt, but it should be applied to Delphi application if you have source code of it in Object Pascal. Otherwise grid can't be automated. Or I just don't know another way.